# How to find the row of a dataframe from column value then update row with dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(None,columns= ['Name','Age','Asset'])
df = df.append({'Name':'John','Age':10,'Asset':'Bike'},ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Name':'Sarah','Age':17,'Asset':'Laptop'},ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Name':'Noah','Age':14,'Asset':'Book'},ignore_index=True)
df

    Name    Age     Asset
0   John    10  Bike
1   Sarah   17  Laptop
2   Noah    14  Book
```

Now I want to take a dictionary `{'Name' :'John','Age':11,'Asset' :'Phone'}` and finds the row of the df with name John, change the age to 11 and Change the Asset to 'Phone'. Assume every column of the dataframe is a key in the dicionary.

since iloc retrieves a row, I thought this would work,

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'John'] = {'Name' :'John','Age':11,'Asset' :'Phone'}
```

However, this doesn't work and you need to update with a list.

What's the efficient way to update a dataframe row with a dictionary?

Comment: `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'John'] = pd.Series({'Name' :'John','Age':11,'Asset' :'Phone'})`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That Updates Name, Age and Asset with Nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the index to Name and then call [`df.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update the dataframe referring to the matching index. Finally `.reset_index()` to reset the index to columns:

```
d={'Name' :'John','Age':11,'Asset' :'Phone'}
```

---

```
d_=pd.DataFrame().from_dict(d,'index').T
m_=df.set_index('Name')
m_.update(d_)
df=m_.reset_index()
```

---

```
    Name Age   Asset
0   John  11   Phone
1  Sarah  17  Laptop
2   Noah  14    Book
```

Comment: Does this work even when the dictionary keys are not in the order of the column names of the df?

Comment: @Qwertford as long as you set `Name` as index, order wont matter. It would work

Comment: @Qwertford you can also try with `pd.concat([d_,df],sort=False).drop_duplicates('Name').reindex(df.columns,axis=1)` for unordered dicts

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make the changes to more than just John? But for any dictionary?

Let's set the dictionary you provided as

```
di = {'Name' :'John','Age':11,'Asset' :'Phone'}
```

Then we can filter using .loc rows by 'Name', and select columns 'Age' and 'Asset', then set values from the dictionary.

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == di['Name'], ['Age', 'Asset']] = [di['Age'], di['Asset']]

print(df)

    Name Age   Asset
0   John  11   Phone
1  Sarah  17  Laptop
2   Noah  14    Book
```

Comment: isn't there a way to match the dictionary keys to the column names to avoid hard coding every combination? df.append() takes in dictionaries and uses None to replace missing key values, isn't there something like that for updating the dataframe too?

Comment: See @anky_91 below, That is the better answer. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You may assign `dict.values()` directly to the the slice you want modify by `.loc` as follows (***Note***: this works on Python 3.5+ because the order of `d` is guaranteed by the insertion order. On Python < 3.5, you need use `collections.OrderedDict`):

```
d = {'Name' :'John','Age':11,'Asset' :'Phone'}
df.loc[df.Name.eq(d['Name']), :] = list(d.values())

Out[643]:
    Name Age   Asset
0   John  11   Phone
1  Sarah  17  Laptop
2   Noah  14    Book
```

Comment: Isn't this risky since list(d.values()) might not give you the values in the order of the columns? The keys of the dictionary could be in any order.

Comment: Python 3.5+ guarantees insertion order. Therefore,  if you create dictionary as specific order as in `d = {'Name' :'John','Age':11,'Asset' :'Phone'}`. It is guaranteed the order of `Name -> Age -> Asset`. However, If you don't have control on how the dictionary was created, this won't work.